# Cannot process a csv file into a pandas with tickers, and fetch stock-info from the DataFrame

Tags: csv, python-3.x, pandas, stock, ticker

I am trying to import a list of stock-tickers (the line that is #symbols_list...read_csv..), and fetch stock-info on that date into a pandas.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

#symbols_list = [pd.read_csv('Stock List.csv', index_col=0)]
symbols_list = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'YHOO','GOOG', 'MSFT','ALTR','WDC','KLAC']
symbols=[]

start = datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9)
#end = datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 30)

for ticker in symbols_list:
    r = DataReader(ticker, "yahoo",
                   start = start)
                   #start=start, end)
    # add a symbol column
    r['Symbol'] = ticker
    symbols.append(r)
# concatenate all the dfs
df = pd.concat(symbols)
#define cell with the columns that i need
cell= df[['Symbol','Open','High','Low','Adj Close','Volume']]
#changing sort of Symbol (ascending) and Date(descending) setting Symbol as first column and changing date format
cell.reset_index().sort(['Symbol', 'Date'], ascending=[1,0]).set_index('Symbol').to_csv('stock.csv', date_format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

The input file Stock list.csv
has the following content with these entries on each their separate row:

```
Index
MMM
ABT
ABBV
ACE
ACN
ACT
ADBE
ADT
AES
AET
AFL
AMG
```

and many more tickers of interest.

When run with the manually coded list

```
symbols_list = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'YHOO','GOOG', 'MSFT','ALTR','WDC','KLAC']
```

It all works fine and processes the input and stores it to a file,
But whenever I run the code with the read_csv from file, I get the following error:

```
runfile('Z:/python/CrystallBall/SpyderProject/getstocks3.py', wdir='Z:/python/CrystallBall/SpyderProject') Reloaded modules: pandas.io.data, pandas.tseries.common Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-32-67cbdd367f48>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('Z:/python/CrystallBall/SpyderProject/getstocks3.py', wdir='Z:/python/CrystallBall/SpyderProject')

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPython-32bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 601, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPython-32bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 80, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "Z:/python/CrystallBall/SpyderProject/getstocks3.py", line 35, in <module>
    cell.reset_index().sort(['Symbol', 'Date'], ascending=[1,0]).set_index('Symbol').to_csv('stock.csv', date_format='%d/%m/%Y')

  File "C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1947, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))

AttributeError: 'Panel' object has no attribute 'reset_index'
```

Why can I only process the symbol_list manually laid out, and not the imported tickers from file?

Any takers?   Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you create a df, doesn't matter if it's from a csv or not, when you iterate over it, what is returned is the column names, not each row entry: `for ticker in symbols_list:` will not return what you expect. You'd have to do something like for `row in symbols_list.index:` and then pass the row as the symbol

Comment: Also it is a bit weird what you are doing, you are creating a list from the call to `read_csv` why? this will create a list with a single df present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has numerous issues which the following code has fixed and works:

```
In [4]:

import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

temp='''Index
MMM
ABT
ABBV
ACE
ACN
ACT
ADBE
ADT
AES
AET
AFL
AMG'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), index_col=[0])
symbols=[]

start = datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9)

for ticker in df.index:
    r = DataReader(ticker, "yahoo",
                   start = start)
                   #start=start, end)
    # add a symbol column
    r['Symbol'] = ticker
    symbols.append(r)
# concatenate all the dfs
df = pd.concat(symbols)
#define cell with the columns that i need
cell= df[['Symbol','Open','High','Low','Adj Close','Volume']]
#changing sort of Symbol (ascending) and Date(descending) setting Symbol as first column and changing date format
cell.reset_index().sort(['Symbol', 'Date'], ascending=[1,0]).set_index('Symbol').to_csv('stock.csv', date_format='%d/%m/%Y')
cell
Out[4]:
           Symbol    Open    High     Low  Adj Close   Volume
Date                                                         
2014-02-10    MMM  129.65  130.41  129.02     126.63  3317400
2014-02-11    MMM  129.70  131.49  129.65     127.88  2604000
...           ...     ...     ...     ...        ...      ...
2015-02-06    AMG  214.35  215.82  212.64     214.45   424400

[3012 rows x 6 columns]
```

So firstly this: `symbols_list = [pd.read_csv('Stock List.csv', index_col=0)]`

This will create a list with a single entry which will be a df with no columns and just an index of your ticker values.

This: `for ticker in symbols_list:`

won't work because the iterable object that is returned from the df is the column and not each entry, in your case you need to iterate over the index which is what my code does.

I'm not sure what you wanted to achieve, it isn't necessary to specify that `index_col=0` if there is only one column, you can either create a df with just a single column, or if you pass `squeeze=True` this will create a Series which just has a single column.

Comment: Thanks guys, EdChum your answer is probably the most helpful to me.

Comment: Thanks guys, EdChum your answer is probably the most helpful to me. I have a couple of questions though.

The code does not compute in my setup. I get an io error from the line.
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), index_col=[0])

Furthermore I do not understand your first lines...?
What does temp = specify? you use a ''' ''' indicating that the tickers are just comments?

I want to import contents of a file (tickers), I know that I am creating a pandas with only index column. This I would like populated with the respective tickers day stock-info, running the iterative loop.

Comment: @MortenE you're not supposed to copy that part verbatim, it's just a method for treating a string as a file object, so ignore the temp part and just use this: `symbols_list = pd.read_csv('Stock List.csv', index_col=0)`

Comment: OK Thanks for your efforts and the clarification Ed, Then when loading my file, like before, I get an error that 'name 'df' is not defined.

Comment: @MortenE again my code uses the variable name `df` for the dataframe, in your instance either follow the same convention os use `symbol_list` you should be using my code and adapt your code not just run it in place of yours, you're supposed to understand the code

Comment: I have  seen an odd behavior as the pandas datareader only works if these conditions are met:
- Either the list of tickers is very short as in below 5 (then the no. of downloaded days can be only 1)
- Or if the list of tickers is long - then it will fail if the number of downloaded days are less than 22 days!

Or it will fail with this error:
OSError: after 3 tries, Yahoo! did not return a 200 for url 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=COV&a=1&b=18&c=2015&d=1&e=18&f=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv'

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: You should post a new question about this